# Can't return each element from a set when running it through a for all loop

Tags: vdm++, vdm-sl

I am trying to return each element from a set containing Brewage objects by running it through a for all loop. But the return value gets messed up when i try to do so.

The loop function:

```
public pure Scan: set of Brewage ==> Brewage
Scan(brewage) == 
for all q in set brewage do 
return q
```

Brewage Constructor:

```
public StringType = seq of char;
public StringLabel = seq of char;
public Char = char; 

instance variables
type : StringType;
label : StringLabel;
deposit : Char;

operations

public Brewage: StringType * StringLabel * Char  ==> Brewage
Brewage(ty, la, de) ==
(   type    := ty;
    label   := la;
    deposit := de
);
```

The error i get is in the Scan function and is the following:

Operation returns void value. Actual: (() | Brewage) Expected: Brewage

Answer (score 0):

You can use a let binding to select a Brewage in the set and then return it:

```
public pure Scan: set of Brewage ==> Brewage
Scan(brewage) == let b in set brewage in return b;

public main: ()==>Brewage
main()==
(
  let s = { new Brewage(), new Brewage() } in
    return Scan(s); 
);
```

Comment: I can't get that to return each element from the set. When i run a test it only returns the first element.

Comment: Do you mean that you want successive calls to Scan to return one Brewage instance? Each call either has to return one, or return a subset or subsequence perhaps. If you want successive calls to return individual items, you have to maintain some state to say which values have already been returned.

Comment: (Incidentally, you get that error because if the set of objects passed is empty, the for loop will drop  through and the operation returns "void")

Comment: Okay. So if i want to use a for all loop, then i first need to check if the set is non empty.

Comment: Or how should i approach this if i want to use the for all loop?